# Determine probability of a biased coin

Tags: probability

You have a set of $m$ coins, each coin is individually biased, with a probability $p$ showing head when tossed. $p$ is sampled out of a uniform distribution $U(0, 1)$.

You draw a coin, flip it $n$ times and it shows head every time.

What's its probability $p$?

Comment: What sort of answer are you hoping for?  Clearly $p$ is not determined by this observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maximum likelihood estimate of $p$ is one which maximizes the likelihood $f(x | p)$ of the observed data. $f(x | p) = p^n$. Clearly, MLE estimate is then $\hat{p} = 1$

But you have a prior distribution $g(p)$ over $p$, so maximum a posteriori estimate is one which maximizes $g(p) * f(x | p)$. But in this case, prior is uninformative since it is uniform. So MAP estimate  = MLE estimate = 1.